# MySQL How to sum rows over a range of timestamps?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, sum, aggregate

Given a table with a timestamp column, e.g.:

```
    timestamp           |  id  |  value  
    --------------------------------------
    2001-01-01 00:00:00 |  1   |  3
    2001-01-01 00:00:00 |  2   |  5
    --------------------------------------
    2001-01-02 00:00:00 |  1   |  6
    2001-01-02 00:00:00 |  2   |  10
    2001-01-02 00:00:00 |  3   |  7
    --------------------------------------
    2001-01-03 00:00:00 |  3   |  14
    2001-01-03 00:00:00 |  2   |  15
    --------------------------------------
    2001-01-03 00:00:00 |  1   |  9
    2001-01-03 00:00:00 |  2   |  20
```

and a given aggregation level, say **2 day**, I would like to aggregate (sum) the results over:
(1) a moving window of the given agg-level, for the above example: 2001-01-01 to 2001-01-02, 2001-01-02 to 2001-01-03, 2001-01-03 to 2001-01-04 which will result in:

```
    timestamp_1         | timestamp_2         |  id  |  agg_value  
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    2001-01-01 00:00:00 | 2001-01-02 00:00:00 |  1   |  9 (=3+6)
    2001-01-01 00:00:00 | 2001-01-02 00:00:00 |  2   |  15 (=5+10)
    2001-01-01 00:00:00 | 2001-01-02 00:00:00 |  3   |  7 (=7)
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    2001-01-02 00:00:00 | 2001-01-03 00:00:00 |  1   |  6 (=6)
    2001-01-02 00:00:00 | 2001-01-03 00:00:00 |  2   |  25 (=10+15)
    2001-01-02 00:00:00 | 2001-01-03 00:00:00 |  3   |  21 (=7+14)
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    2001-01-03 00:00:00 | 2001-01-04 00:00:00 |  1   |  9 (=9)
    2001-01-03 00:00:00 | 2001-01-04 00:00:00 |  2   |  35 (=15+20)
    2001-01-03 00:00:00 | 2001-01-04 00:00:00 |  3   |  14 (=14)
```

(2) non overlapping division to the given range, for the above example: 2001-01-01 to 2001-01-02, 2001-01-03 to 2001-01-04, which will result in:

```
    timestamp_1         | timestamp_2         |  id  |  agg_value  
    -----------------------------------------------------------

    2001-01-01 00:00:00 | 2001-01-02 00:00:00 |  1   |  9 (=3+6)
    2001-01-01 00:00:00 | 2001-01-02 00:00:00 |  2   |  15 (=5+10)
    2001-01-01 00:00:00 | 2001-01-02 00:00:00 |  3   |  7 (=7)
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    2001-01-03 00:00:00 | 2001-01-04 00:00:00 |  1   |  9 (=9)
    2001-01-03 00:00:00 | 2001-01-04 00:00:00 |  2   |  35 (=15+20)
    2001-01-03 00:00:00 | 2001-01-04 00:00:00 |  3   |  14 (=14)
```

(which is basically like (1) without the overlap)

Thanks!

---

Edited: adding a solution

I have a solution at least for (1):

```
    SELECT t1.timestamp AS timestamp1,
    MAX(t2.timestamp) AS timestamp2, t1.id,
    SUM(t2.value) AS agg_value
    FROM my_table t1
    LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON
    (t2.timestamp >= t1.timestamp AND
    t2.timestamp <= ADDDATE(t1.timestamp,INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND
    t2.id = t1.id)
    GROUP BY t1.timestamp, t1.id
```

A solution for (2) can probably be just filtering to a subset of the above.

Comment: are all of the dates going to be in the table? are there gap possibilities? i.e. timestamp_1 contains 1/1/2001, 1/2/2001, 1/3/2001, 1/6/2001, ... would you still want a 1/4-1/5 sum?

Comment: Not all dates are to be in the table, for instance in the example you gave I won't be interested in 1/4-1/5 sum.

Answer (score 0):

This will group by every X days by getting the date portion and getting the date difference and grouping by the days difference, PLUS the ID.  This will get your #2 solution

```
select 
       CEILING( datediff( date( now() ), date( myTimeStamp )) / 2 ) DaysDiff,
       ID,
       min( date( myTimeStamp )) as FirstDateInGroup,
       max( date( myTimeStamp )) as LastDateInGroup,
       sum( value ) as SumVal
   FROM TimeSample
   group by DaysDiff, ID
   order by FirstDateInGroup, ID
```

EDIT ---- PER COMMENTS

Your sample was showing how to handle for 2 days... so does this.  The "now()" is just a baseline to group your data.  If you want it broken down by years, then I would just do a query based on the YEAR( YourDateColumn ) as the group.  If you want 30 days, just divide by 30.  Monthly, I would group by year( YourDateColumn ) and month( YourDateColumn ) respectively.  By having a fixed "now()" range, its doing nothing but returning a number as a starting point.  If your data was 2 years old, the date difference would just be 365days * 2 years = 730 days... Divide by 2 and your back at a group basis of 365.  You can throw whatever where clause you want to further limit the time period you are interested in...

where myTimeStamp between '2011-01-01' and '2011-06-30' to get just the first 6 months of this year...   That would result with your DaysDiff grouping of 208 days / 2 = 104.

So, if you have some other baseline value you care to make your groupings, you can just change the now() to something like '2011-01-01' and it will compute based on Jan 1, 2011 basis.  Of which, this will do nothing but compute the DaysDiff to negative values up to zero, then back to positive.

Comment: One problem with your solution though, the reference point is now() and not the lower bound timestamp of the range, so if I have:<br>
2010-01-01<br>
2010-07-01<br>
2010-08-01<br>
2010-12-01<br>
2011-03-01<br>
2011-05-01<br>
and the aggregation level is set to **1 year** and now() is 2011-07-27, I'll get the division:<br>
2010-01-01 - 2010-07-01<br>
2010-08-01 - 2011-05-01<br>
instead of:<br>
2010-01-01 - 2010-12-01<br>
2011-03-01 - 2011-05-01<br>
Any thoughts how to solve this problem?

Comment: One problem with your solution though, the reference point is now() and not the lower bound timestamp of the range, so if I have:
`2010-01-01<br>
2010-07-01<br>
2010-08-01<br>
2010-12-01<br>
2011-03-01<br>
2011-05-01<br>`
and the aggregation level is set to **1 year** and now() is 2011-07-27, I'll get the division:
`2010-01-01 - 2010-07-01<br>
2010-08-01 - 2011-05-01<br>`
instead of:
`2010-01-01 - 2010-12-01<br>
2011-03-01 - 2011-05-01<br>`
Any thoughts how to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks @DRapp, I used the earliest timestamp in the database as baseline and got the results I wanted (the timestamp db is read-only so I can assume it's a fixed timestamp). Thanks!